# Android: timestamps

Tags: android, timestamp

Can anyone help me on how to put time stamps and how to put message details in list view in a database? Just like on mobile phones, name of the contact, time and some part of his message is displayed. Here's the code for my database:

```
public class MessagesDBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_RECIPIENT = "recipient";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "MessagesDBAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


     //Database creation sql statement

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public MessagesDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public MessagesDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createNote(String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        open();

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_RECIPIENT,
                KEY_MESSAGE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_RECIPIENT, KEY_MESSAGE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String phoneNo, String message) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        args.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get timestamp by call System.currentTimeMillis();

if you want show in readable formate, just try SimpleDateFormat
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html